# Calculate volume weighted average price of trades based on the last traded 500 units of volume in azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I have streaming data coming from eventhub as follows:

```
product  price  quantity 
 1        55      100
 2        44      200
 2        43      200
 1        60      300
 2        55      100
 2        44      50
 2        47      100
 1        44      100
 1        48      100
```

Now I want to calculate the volume weighted average price grouped by product but always only of the last 500 units of traded volume (not of all values).

Calculating based on a time windows is straight forward but I want to only aggregate over the last 500 units of traded volume instead.

So I am looking for some kind of windowing function without time constraint. Is that existing or even possible with stream analytics?

Comment: last 500 units of traded volume-- **How do you determine the last 500 units ? do you have any timestamp or rownumber fields?**

Comment: yes there exist a timestamp for each event

Answer (score 0):

The formula for weighted average is:

```
weighted_average = sum of (value * weight) / sum of weights
```

Since you have timestamp, you can use that field to compute the weighted average of price based on quantity column for each product with a window frame that includes all rows within the last 500 seconds. Below is the query

**Query:**

```
with Stgquery as(
select
product,  SUM(price)  OVER  (PARTITION  BY product LIMIT  DURATION  (second, 500))  as denom,
sum(cast(price as float)  *  cast(quantity as float))  over  (PARTITION  by product LIMIT  DURATION  (second, 500))  as num
from
input)
select product,weighted_average=(num/denom)  from Stgquery
```

In this query, CTE  `stgquery` selects the  `product`, the cumulative sum of the  `price`  column for each group of  `product`  values, and the sum of the product of the  `price`  and  `quantity`  columns for each group of  `product`  values ( using the  `SUM`  function with a window frame that includes all rows within the last 500 seconds. This can be changed as per requirement). The  `SELECT`  statement selects the  `product`  column and calculates the weighted average of the  `price`  column based on the  `quantity`  column for each group of  `product`  values. The weighted average is calculated by dividing the sum of the product of the  `price`  and  `quantity`  columns (stored in the  `num`  column of the  `Stgquery`  CTE) by the cumulative sum of the  `price`  column (stored in the  `denom`  column of the  `Stgquery`  CTE). The result is returned as a new column named  `weighted_average`.

**Output:**

| product | weighted_average |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 1 | 204.3478 |
| 2 | 161.2676 |
| 2 | 134.9462 |
| 2 | 127.897 |
| 1 | 175.4717 |
| 1 | 157.971 |

Comment: This is the vwap over the last 500 seconds but not what I am looking for. I want the vwap over the last 500 quantitites.

Comment: 500 quantities -- the last row itself has 100 quanties. if you have 500 quanties in one row, should you consider that only? Could you explain

Comment: yes, if you have eg. 500 quanties in one row this is the only record you should take into account for the vwap. as long as the sum of quantities is less than 500 take the vwap of all records. If a new event is coming in and the limit of 500 quantities is exceeded, remove the first event (regarding tms) from the group to calculate the vwap with the new record

Comment: Have you tried any approach? do you have atleast partial working code? This could help me to understand the scenario better.